Is it possible to immediately convert input to a double array on Java?
My project for a calculus course is to create a program that finds the intersection of any two lines or planes. However, I haven't coded in a year, so I've forgotten a lot of coding. I feel like my code is very repetitive and could be simplified.
In this code, I am asking the user for the position and direction vectors of two lines and storing it into a double array. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this. For example, is it possible to directly store the input into a double array? Thanks.
System.out.println("Input the position vector of the first line in the format x,y,z with no spaces.");
String posv1 = vscanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Input the direction vector of the first line in the format x,y,z with no spaces.");
String dirv1 = vscanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Input the position vector of the second line in the format x,y,z with no spaces.");
String posv2 = vscanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Input the direction vector of the second line in the format x,y,z with no spaces.");
String dirv2 = vscanner.nextLine();

vscanner.close();

//split all vectors at commas and place in array
String[] posv1s = posv1.split(","); String[] dirv1s = dirv1.split(","); String[] posv2s = posv2.split(","); String[] dirv2s = dirv2.split(","); 

//convert string array to double array
double[] posv1d = Arrays.stream(posv1s).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
double[] dirv1d = Arrays.stream(dirv1s).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();   
double[] posv2d = Arrays.stream(posv2s).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
double[] dirv2d = Arrays.stream(dirv2s).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();


It seems that you have code that is working and there is no question. Stackoverflow is about Q&A. You probably want a code review. Stackoverflow is not the right place for that. Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Try it like this.
double posv1 = vscanner.nextDouble();

I would store them in a List since lists grow dynamically .   To fetch a value at index i, use <listname>.get(i). Here is an example
that allows for errored input.

It also will loop thru the array and lists and store in each sublist or array.
prompts for each input
alerts if the input is  not appropriate (e.g. a string)
allows eroneous input to be caught and reprompted by modifying the loop variable.

Scanner vscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
vscanner.useDelimiter(",|\r");
int nValues = 4;
String[] prompts = {
        "Input the position vector of the first line in the format x,y,z with no spaces.",
        "Input the direction vector of the first line in the format x,y,z with no spaces.",
        "Input the position vector of the second line in the format x,y,z with no spaces.",
        "Input the direction vector of the second line in the format x,y,z with no spaces."};

List<Double> lposv1d = new ArrayList<>();
List<Double> ldirv1d = new ArrayList<>();
List<Double> lposv2d = new ArrayList<>();
List<Double> ldirv2d = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Double>> lallValues = 
   new ArrayList<>(List.of(lposv1d, ldirv1d, lposv2d,
        ldirv2d));

double[] posv1d = new double[3];
double[] dirv1d = new double[3];
double[] posv2d = new double[3];
double[] dirv2d = new double[3];
double[][] allValues = {posv1d,dirv1d,posv2d,dirv2d};

int i;
for (i = 0; i < nValues; i++) {
    try {
        System.out.println(prompts[i]);
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            double v = vscanner.nextDouble();
            lallValues.get(i).add(v);
            // or
            allValues[i][k] = v;
        }
        vscanner.nextLine();// eliminate new line from buffer
    } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
        System.out.println(
                "Floating point value not entered, try again:");
        vscanner.nextLine(); // clear bad input
        lallValues.get(i).clear(); // remove tainted input.
        i--; // reset i to repeat the prompt
        
    }

}
for (int i = 0; i < nValues; i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allValues[i]));
}
System.out.println();
for (int i = 0; i < nValues; i++) {
    System.out.println(lallValues.get(i));
}


To reduce the repetitiveness, you can define a method to get this set of inputs since the number of inputs and their type are the same.
public static double[] getInputs(Scanner scanner) {
    double[] arr = new double[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arr[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
    }
    return arr;
}

and call it each time to get input
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input the position vector of the first line");
double[] posv1 = getInputs(scanner);
// repeat the same for the rest.


I advise you to use OOP.
I think the Point and Line classes need to be placed in separate files, I left them here for clarity. In addition, methods except main can be transferred to other classes.
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    private static final String INPUT_PATTERN = "Input the %s of the %s line in the format x,y,z with no spaces: ";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var firstLine = getLineByInput("first");
        var secondLine = getLineByInput("second");
        
        System.out.println(firstLine);
        System.out.println(secondLine);
    }
    
    public static Line getLineByInput(String lineName) {
        var position = getPointByInput(lineName, "position");
        System.out.println("__________________________________\n");
        var direction = getPointByInput(lineName, "direction");
        System.out.println("__________________________________\n");
        return new Line(position, direction);
    }
    
    public static Point getPointByInput(String lineName, String pointName) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(String.format(INPUT_PATTERN, pointName, lineName));
            try {
                return convertPoint(scanner.nextLine());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("format x,y,z with no spaces, try again: \n");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static Point convertPoint(String str) {
        var doubles = Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
            .map(Double::parseDouble)
            .toArray(Double[]::new);
        if(doubles.length != 3) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        return new Point(doubles[0], doubles[1], doubles[2]);
    }
    
    static class Point {
        private double x;
        private double y;
        private double z;
        
        public Point(double x, double y, double z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("x: %f, y: %f, z: %f", x, y, z);
        }
    }
    
    static class Line {
        private Point position;
        private Point direction;
        
        public Line (Point position, Point direction) {
            this.position = position;
            this.direction = direction;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("position: %s \ndirection: %s", position, direction);
        }
    }
}

